# How to set column width and space between columns with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

This code is working fine, but I would like to make the columns larger and have less space between them, how can I do this using `pgfplots`?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#Percentage},
    symbolic x coords={Slow,Medium,Fast},
    xtick=data,
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Slow,90.7) (Medium,89.3) (Fast,93.7)};
\addplot coordinates {(Slow,39.7) (Medium,43.3) (Fast,39.6)};
\legend{Messages received,Messages retransmitted}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the width of the bars with `bar width`. In addition I think you need `enlarge x limits` to avoid clipping of bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    bar width=25,enlarge x limits=0.25, %  <--- added
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={\#Percentage},
    symbolic x coords={Slow,Medium,Fast},
    xtick=data,
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
\addplot coordinates {(Slow,90.7) (Medium,89.3) (Fast,93.7)};
\addplot coordinates {(Slow,39.7) (Medium,43.3) (Fast,39.6)};
\legend{Messages received,Messages retransmitted}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```